# Creating Dynamic Locks at Runtime in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, thread-safety

Are the following assumptions valid for this code?  I put some background info under the code, but I don't think it's relevant.

**Assumption 1:** Since this is a single application, I'm making the assumption it will be handled by a single process. Thus, static variables are shared between threads, and declaring my collection of lock objects statically is valid.

**Assumption 2:** If I know the value is already in the dictionary, I don't need to lock on read.  I could use a ConcurrentDictionary, but I believe this one will be safe since I'm not enumerating (or deleting), and the value will exist and not change when I call `UnlockOnValue()`.

**Assumption 3:** I can lock on the Keys collection, since that reference won't change, even if the underlying data structure does.

```
private static Dictionary<String,Object> LockList = 
    new Dictionary<string,object>();

private void LockOnValue(String queryStringValue)
{
    lock(LockList.Keys)
    {
        if(!LockList.Keys.Contains(queryStringValue))
        {
            LockList.Add(screenName,new Object());
        }
        System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(LockList[queryStringValue]);
    }
}

private void UnlockOnValue(String queryStringValue)
{
    System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(LockList[queryStringValue]);
}
```

Then I would use this code like:

```
LockOnValue(Request.QueryString["foo"])
//Check cache expiry
//if expired
    //Load new values and cache them.
//else
    //Load cached values
UnlockOnValue(Request.QueryString["foo"])
```

**Background:**  I'm creating an app in ASP.NET that downloads data based on a single user-defined variable in the query string.  The number of values will be quite limited.  I need to cache the results for each value for a specified period of time.

**Approach:** I decided to use local files to cache the data, which is not the best option, but I wanted to try it since this is non-critical and performance is not a big issue.  I used 2 files per option, one with the cache expiry date, and one with the data.

**Issue:** I'm not sure what the best way to do locking is, and I'm not overly familiar with threading issues in .NET (one of the reasons I chose this approach).  Based on what's available, and what I read, I thought the above should work, but I'm not sure and wanted a second opinion.

Comment: What's the problem with using `HttpRuntime.Cache`?

Comment: That was my first choice, but it was acting oddly. It may be because my page wipes the response and returns a text file, but I didn't dig too deeply after running into similar issues posted all the Internet, with no answers that worked for me. The only thing I didn't get into was the IIS configuration and whether or not caching was configured correctly. I may still do that later, but it's such non-critical code and this raised questions that I wanted answers to, even if it's not the best architecture.

Comment: I'm trying to implement a very similar solution to yours where I'm caching methods results. I will also need a way of creating different cache locks and I was wondering if your solution has withstood the test of time, cheers.

Comment: It has, but there was very limited load on it and I performed no artificial load testing.  I can't guarantee it, but it certainly does seem to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your current solution looks pretty good.  The two things I would change:

1: UnlockOnValue needs to go in a finally block.  If an exception is thrown, it will never release its lock.

2: LockOnValue is somewhat inefficient, since it does a dictionary lookup twice.  This isn't a big deal for a small dictionary, but for a larger one you will want to switch to TryGetValue.

Also, your assumption 3 holds - at least for now.  But the Dictionary contract makes no guarantee that the Keys property always returns the same object.  And since it's so easy to not rely on this, I'd recommend against it.  Whenever I need an object to lock on, I just create an object for that sole purpose.  Something like:

```
private static Object _lock = new Object();
```

Comment: I should have specified that in the pseudo code, but I have it in the finally block.  I never thought of TryGetValue, but that's probably a better option.  The dictionary will be small, but still good to think about.

Comment: Yeah, it's a pet peeve of mine to see a call to Contains and then a call to [] since they both have to find the element.

Answer (score 1):

`lock` only has a scope of a single process.  If you want to span processes you'll have to use primitives like `Mutex` (named).

`lock` is the same as `Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.Exit`.  If you also do `Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.Exit`, it's being redundant.

You don't need to lock on read, but you do have to lock the "transaction" of checking if the value doesn't exist and adding it.  If you don't lock on that series of instructions, something else could come in between when you check for the key and when you add it and add it--thus resulting in an exception.  The lock you're doing is sufficient to do that (you don't need the additional calls to Enter and Exit--lock will do that for you).

Comment: I'm assuming all threads for this application are going to be coming from the same process.  The documentation and examples I've looked at all point to that being the case, although I'm still not 100% sure.  It's really my second assumption I'm not really sure about.  I think the first is correct, and the third is probably correct, but there's no reason to do that over just creating a lock object for the dictionary (i.e. might work, but probably bad code)

Comment: If it's one application and all the threads are in a single instance of the process, lock fits that situation.