# c# Dynamic Lock for I/O access

Tags: c#, thread-safety, locking

I have a method called DownloadFileAsync that download a file and another called GetLocalFilePathAsync that returns a file path.

My issue is that GetLocalFilePathAsync is called while DownloadFileAsync is not complete leading to zero bytes files and errors.

I tried to implement a dyanmic lock based on that question:
[Creating Dynamic Locks at Runtime in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617616/creating-dynamic-locks-at-runtime-in-asp-net)

Here is my code.

```
public static class DynamicLock
{
    private static Dictionary<string, AsyncLock> LockList = new Dictionary<string, AsyncLock>();
    private static readonly object lockDic = new AsyncLock();

    public static void LockOnValue(string lockKey)
    {
        lock (lockDic)
        {
            AsyncLock obj = null;
            if (!LockList.TryGetValue(lockKey, out obj))
            {
                obj = new AsyncLock();
                LockList.Add(lockKey, obj);
            }
            Monitor.Enter(obj);
            //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"LockList count: {LockList.Count} {lockKey} locked,  Value = {obj}");
        }
    }

    public static void UnlockOnValue(string lockKey)
    {
        Monitor.Exit(LockList[lockKey]);
    }
}

public static async Task<string> GetLocalFilePathAsync(string itemId, string fileName)
    {
        var lockKey = $"{itemId}_{fileName}";
        DynamicLock.LockOnValue(lockKey);
        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"PATH ACCESS FILE {lockKey}");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemId) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
                return null;
            IPlatform platform = DependencyService.Get<IPlatform>();
            string recordFilesPath = Path.Combine(await platform.GetFilesPathAsync(), itemId);
            var checkExists = await FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage.CheckExistsAsync(recordFilesPath);
            if (checkExists == ExistenceCheckResult.NotFound)
                return null;
            return Path.Combine(recordFilesPath, fileName);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            DynamicLock.UnlockOnValue(lockKey);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"PATH UNLOCK {lockKey}");
        }
    }

public static async Task DownloadFileAsync<T>(IMobileServiceSyncTable<T> table, MobileServiceFile file)
    {
        var lockKey = $"{file.ParentId}_{file.Name}";
        DynamicLock.LockOnValue(lockKey);
        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"DOWNALOAD FILE {lockKey}");
            var platform = DependencyService.Get<IPlatform>();
            await platform.DownloadFileAsync(table, file);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            DynamicLock.UnlockOnValue(lockKey);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"DOWNALOAD UNLOCK {lockKey}");
        }
    }
```

And from the log:

DOWNALOAD FILE e7152b72-adf6-4615-b5f9-e77e3ca4345b_IMG_20160219_101743.jpg

PATH ACCESS FILE e7152b72-adf6-4615-b5f9-e77e3ca4345b_IMG_20160219_101743.jpg

PATH UNLOCK e7152b72-adf6-4615-b5f9-e77e3ca4345b_IMG_20160219_101743.jpg

ERROR

So GetLocalFilePathAsync is executed before that DownloadFileAsyncreleases the lock.

What am I missing?

Tks.

Comment: Show your code that calls both `GetLocalFilePathAsync` and `DownloadFileAsync`, the problem is likely in that code, not the methods themselves.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain The update works.

Comment: Then post it as an answer and accept it or delete your question.

Comment: Sur will do. Need to wait 2 days before marking it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing my quesiton here made me rethink it and the below seems to work (I got to test it thoroughly though).

```
public static class DynamicLock
{
    private static Dictionary<string, AsyncLock> LockList = new Dictionary<string, AsyncLock>();
    private static readonly object lockDic = new AsyncLock();

    public static async Task<T> LockOnKey<T>(string lockKey, Func<Task<T>> criticalFunc)
    {
        AsyncLock obj = null;
        lock (lockDic)
        {

            if (!LockList.TryGetValue(lockKey, out obj))
            {
                obj = new AsyncLock();
                LockList.Add(lockKey, obj);
            }
        }
        using (var releaser = await obj.LockAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
        { 
            return await criticalFunc();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That was not a acceptable answer. I took what you put in the UPDATE section in here and removed it from your question.